# AngularJS Mock Self Executing Controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, backbone.js, angular-mock

How do I prevent an angular controller with a self instantiating function from executing for tests?

(I have used a contrived example to illustrate my issue)

I have a controller that executes some code on startup (in my case ajax)

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function () {
    this.doSomething = function () {
        console.log('nahh');
    };

    this.doSomething();
});
```

I am attempting to write a test for the controller. I don't want **doSomething** to execute.

```
var ctrl = $controller('myCtrl',
{
    $scope: {}
});
// ctrl.doSomething has already run!

expect(something).to.be(true);
```

When using backbone.js I would do something like:

```
MyCtrl.prototype.doSomething = function(){};
myCtrl = new MyCtrl();
```

I modify the prototype before initialisation to prevent execution. $controller appears to give me an instance of the controller. It would be useful to be able to get the prototype. There may be other ways to overcome this I am not aware of!

Comment: A way I got around it was to use *ng-init* on the dom element to bootstrap. That way it would not bootstrap in code.

**js**
    
`app.controller('myCtrl', function () {
$scope.doSomething = function () {
console.log('nahh');
};
});`

**HTML**
`<div ng-controller="myCtrl" ng-init="doSomething()">`

Comment: Actually you can add the doSomething function to the Ctrl prototype (some would even say you better do it in that way for better performance).  If you would pass to the controller registration an Object instead if the anonymous function, you could than just add to that object's prototype the methods you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comment, I got around this problem by putting my intialisation code in an `init` function. I then used `ng-init` to start this code when it is on the dom. This allowed me to test the controller in code without it starting itself.

JS:

```
$scope.init = function() {
  doSomething();
};
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="myController" ng-init="init()">
```